# Keyboard shortcut to display music library in iTunes

Tags: itunes, keyboard

So assuming that I'm in a playlist I'd like to be able to type a keyboard shortcut and then have my music library display on the main panel and then tab to the search bar and look for a song.

Comment: If you are looking to find 'Any extra useful keyboard shortcuts/commands?' in general, please make that a separate post. I've changed your title accordingly for this question. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see one, so it is probably applescript to the rescue

Answer (score 1):

Just use <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

If you start with the focus on the playlist and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the focus will go to the sidebar. You can start typing `Mus` and the Music library will display in the main panel. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again. The focus will jump to the search bar. Start typing the song you're looking for. Hit <kbd>tab</kbd> again and you're back in the main window where you started.

You can use <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> to jump to the search box at any time regardless of where the focus is.

It sounds like you'd benefit from an app launcher with built-in iTunes launch/search navigation. [Quicksilver](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http://www.blacktree.com/&rct=j&q=quicksilver%20mac&ei=L0iqTZiLOOnl0QHpntH5CA&usg=AFQjCNEJTIZu-3GljKYIFKJVDNCjtPmGKg&cad=rja) and [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/) are both good choices.

Answer (score 1):

The script works perfectly when I run it from the AppleScript editor, but when I run it from the iTunes scripts menu it

1. takes about 7 seconds to run
2. changes my view to music, but doesn't leave the cursor in the search field

I ensured enable access for assistive devices is checked.  It's frustrating as it does exactly what I want when running from the editor.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A little Applescript along these lines will work:

```
try
tell application "iTunes"
    activate
    set winname to name of browser window 1
    set view of window winname to playlist "Music"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "iTunes"
        set (value of text field 1 of window winname) to ""
        set focused of text field 1 of window winname to true
    end tell
end tell
on error
```

beep 1
end try

Put the script in /Users/.../Library/iTunes/Scripts to see it in your iTunes script Menu. You'll have to turn on "Enable Access for assistive devices" in the 'Universal Access' Preferences pane to let the script work. You can also add a keyboard shortcut to run the script when you're in iTunes thru the 'Keyboard Shortcuts' pane of the Keyboard preferences pane.